# efficiently join url in python without string concatenation

Tags: python, url, urllib

I am trying to join a url but at the moment have a very manual way of doing it and wondered if there is a more efficient way.

I have the homepage with I have parsed using `urlparse`. I also have the end link which I am trying to join with both the scheme and the domain name. The code is as such:

```
url = 'https://www.windex.com/en-us'
link = '/en-us/products/outdoor-sprayer'

parsed_url = urlparse(url)
full_url = parsed_url.scheme + '://' + parsed_url.netloc + link
```

This gives https://www.windex.com/en-us/products/outdoor-sprayer which is correct and directs me to the right page. Is there a better way to do this other than string concatenation? I tried `urljoin` as follows but got the wrong result:

```
urljoin(parsed_url.scheme, parsed_url.netloc, link)
Output: 'www.windex.com'
```

Many Thanks

Comment: do you mean [urllib.parse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) ? it doesn't get `scheme`, `netloc`, `link` but `base`, `url`

Answer (score 2):

If you mean [urllib.parse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) then you use it in wrong way because it needs only `base` and `url`

```
import urllib

url = 'https://www.windex.com/en-us/'
link = '/en-us/products/outdoor-sprayer'

full_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, link)
```